# Google Cast Plugin for iOS in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Trying to get Chromecast to work on a iOS ARKit application with the Google Cast Remote Display Plugin for Unity, using this guide from Google:

[Remote Unity - Google.com](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote_unity)

I carefully followed all the provided steps, several times both video and online documentation.

But I must be missing something. Because it won't find my Chromecast device.

Anybody succeeded in making it work on iOS using the plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Support for the Cast Plugin for Unity has been deprecated and the plugin hasn't been updated in a long time. Discovery issues are typically related to having the wrong serial number registered in the Google Cast Console. If its not that then any issues with the plugin are unlikely to be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, so best bet is to start working on the Unity build in Xcode and use the currently provided Google setup for iOS here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_setup

Comment: Yes, you will essentially have to create your own plugin with the cast sender sdk.